# How to open a file whose name is given within another file in Emacs

Tags: emacs, gnu, elisp

For example, if my `A.txt` contains the following line:

```
summary is at: /summary/is/at/summary.txt
```

how can I open `summary.txt` without having to copy-paste the path, or write the whole path after `C-x C-f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find-file-at-point` function:

1. open `A.txt` with Emacs;
2. move the cursor somewhere in the middle of `/summary/is/at/summary.txt`
3. `M-x find-file-at-point`

You might want to set up a shortcut for it, add to your `~/.emacs`, for example:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'find-file-at-point)
```